# Spring security - intercept-url pattern mapping

Tags: java, spring, security

I've encountered a problem with my application that use spring security.
I have this configuration of http tag in my security config file:

```
 <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" path-type="regex">
     <intercept-url pattern="\A/hero.jsp/$?chooseHero=\Z" access="hasRole('ROLE_HERO')" />
     <intercept-url pattern="/.*" access="permitAll" />
     <logout logout-success-url="/" />              
 </http>
```

There is a problem with the first intercept-url - the address is not matched. It basically means that I anybody can access the /hero.jsp/$?chooseHero= section of my application. Am I missing something? When using only:

```
   <intercept-url pattern="\A/hero.jsp\Z" access="hasRole('ROLE_HERO')" />
```

everything works just fine.

I have database-based authentication implemented.

Please, could you anybody help me with this issue? 
Thank you for any hints or ideas.

Comment: I would try with `$` escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first intercept URL must be a valid regex, it is processed by a [RegexRequestMatcher](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/RegexRequestMatcher.html). This is an odd regex:

```
pattern="\A/hero.jsp/$?chooseHero=\Z"
```

Why do you need the `$`? Is it meant to be matched literally (it has a special meaning in regular expressions)? I guess so... Also, `.` and `?` have [special meanings](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Assuming you want all characters to be matched literally it has to be like this:

```
pattern="\A/hero\.jsp/\$\?chooseHero=\Z"
```

However, if everything is matched literally why do you need a regex at all? You may want to spare yourself the trouble and just use the simpler [Ant-style matchers](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/core-web-filters.html).